# Hide invokerequired code under the class

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

in some class i declare an event like this:

```
public delegate void UserOfflineHandler(string ip);
public event UserOfflineHandler OnUserOffline;
```

then generate event

```
void srvSomeFunc(string ip)
{
    OnUserOffline(ip);
}
```

and on my form i create an event handler

```
srv = new ServerClass(); 
srv.OnUserOffline += srv_OnUserOffline;
```

and inside `srv_OnUserOffline` i want to work with ListBox, so i use delegate

```
delegate void UpdateUserListCallback(string s);

private void updateUserList(string s)
{
    if (listBox2.InvokeRequired)
    {
        UpdateUserListCallback dt = new UpdateUserListCallback(updateUserList);
        Invoke(dt, new object[] { s });
    }
    else
    {
        //some work with listbox
    }
}
```

how can i put this inside my `ServiceClass`, not inside form's code? So in the form's code i will get only something like this:

```
srv.OnUserOffline += srv_OnUserOffline;
```

...

```
void srv_OnUserOffline(string login)
{
    listbox2.Add(login);
}
```

Comment: Never, *never* hide InvokeRequired.  And especially never hide Invoke(), that's a method that is very apt to create deadlock.  You never want to hide the parts of the program that are very expensive (hundreds of microseconds) and very apt to cause a program to fail with horribly undebuggable mishaps.  It is an inconvenient truth that you should very strongly avoid ever having to use.  It *needs* to hurt, if you hide it then you are pretty much guaranteed to create a lousy program.

Comment: @HansPassant i'm with you 100%. Do not try to hide away crucial parts such as this, specially because interface relevant code should remain in the interface!

Answer (score 0):

you can create an [extension](http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension) method for this and use it with any control.

```
public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Control control, Action action)
  {

            if (control.InvokeRequired) {
                control.Invoke(action);
            } else {
                action();
            }
   }
```

here is how you will use it

```
 //I would skip this check but left up to you
 listBox2.InvokeIfRequired(() =>
 {
   // Do anything you want with the control here
   UpdateUserListCallback dt = new UpdateUserListCallback(updateUserList);
   Invoke(dt, new object[] { s });
  });
```

and finally

```
void srv_OnUserOffline(string login)
{ 
      // here you are actually working with List so check Invoke only here

      listBox2.InvokeIfRequired(() =>
      {
                listBox2.Add(login);
      });
}
```